# Is it possible to inject a ServiceWorker into a Chrome app <webview> page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, offline-caching, service-worker

I'd like to use ServiceWorkers to automatically add offline-caching to a page loaded into a [webview](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#method-addContentScripts) tag in a Chrome app. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31515426/how-to-use-inline-service-worker), and the specs I've read it's not possible to inline a ServiceWorker. Is there any way to inject a ServiceWorker to cache the content of `<webview>` tag in a Chrome App?

Comment: I believe the answer is no: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=439323

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question? Wouldn't this suggest that it is possible? http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com.au/2015/03/android-webview-update.html